# Перевести char в string

Tags: char, android, java, строки

Ребят вот такая проблема, выцепляю из переменной типа `string` первый символ так:

```
     char came_buffer;
     String sbprint;
     came_buffer = sbprint.charAt(0);
```

а потом мне нужно этот символ перевести из char в `string`, гугл толкового ответа не даёт, лишь какие-то самописные функции,которые толком не работают

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну я, конечно понимаю, что вопрос смешной, но зачем минусовать то так человека?? По существу ->

[public static String valueOf (char[] data, int start, int length)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char))

> Creates a new string containing the specified characters in the character array. Modifying the character array after creating the string has no effect on the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
char ch = 'S';

// c использованием класса Character
String charToString = Character.toString(ch);
System.out.println(charToString);

// с использованием операции добавления класса String
String str = "" + ch;
System.out.println(str);

//с использованием массива
String fromChar = new String(new char[] { ch });
System.out.println(fromChar);

// с использованием метода valueOf класса String 
String valueOfchar = String.valueOf(ch);
System.out.println(valueOfchar);
```